# SQL calculating running total as you go down the rows but also taking other fields into account

Tags: sql, cursor, rows

I'm hoping you guys can help with this problem.

I have a set of data which I have displayed via excel.

[image: 1]

I'm trying to work out the rolling new cap allowance but need to deduct from previous weeks bookings. I don't want to use a cursor so can anyone help.

I'm going to group by the product id so it will need to start afresh for every product.

In the image, Columns A to D are fixed and I am trying to calculate the data in column E ('New Cap'). The 'New Cap' is the expected results.

Column F gives a detailed formula of what im trying to do.

Not sure what I've done for the post to be marked down.

Thanks

Update:
The formula looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi, no it doesnt as I need to take into account previous weeks booking numbers to calculate a new cap total.

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data as text and expected results, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: in the image, Columns A to D are fixed and I am trying to calculate column E the 'New Cap'. The 'New Cap' is the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You want the sum of the cap through this row minus the sum of booked through the previous row.  This is easy to do with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(cap + booked) over (partition by productid order by weekbeg) - booked
       ) as new_cap
from t;
```

Comment: Hi Gordan, thanks for the quick reply. Apologies as I have not been able to explain the problem well. I have added another image in the above to show what the formula looks like for the 'New Cap' on every row. Thanks

Comment: @Um7an . . . Are you saying this doesn't work?  I'm pretty sure this is the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the new running total using `lag` and `sum over` window functions - calculate the `cap-booked` first, then use `sum over()` for the running total:

```
    select weekbeg, ProductId, Cap, Booked, 
      Sum(n) over(partition by productid order by weekbeg) New_Cap
    from (
      select *, cap - Lag(booked,1,0) over(partition by productid order by weekbeg)n
      from t
    )t
```

Comment: This is brilliant, exactly what I needed. thank you. 

Is it possible to put a case statement around it so that if the New_Cap is < 0 then it uses the CAP for the current week as the running total needs to start over again.

Comment: Is it possibe so that If the New_Cap is < 0 then it only uses the CAP for the current week.


select 
case when Sum(n) over(partition by Productid order by weekbeg)  <0 then t.Cap
 else 
  Sum(n) over(partition by Productid order by weekbeg) 
         end  New_Cap


The only problem with the above  I have is that the running total doesn't start again all I get its the Cap for the following weeks.

Comment: That wasn't particularly clear from your question, looking again at your example spreadsheet, it just resets to 9 and remains 9, that made no sense. I'll give it some more thought it will probably require another nest level.

Comment: thanks @Stu, apologies, first post so still learning how to word it properly.